# Why does the DFT matrix in numpy differ from the math definition?

Tags: fourier-transform

I want to understand the DFT matrix better (starting with the real part first).

1. I'm first computing a DFT matrix by calculating the FFT of an identity matrix ( I can do `sp.linalg.dft` and I get the same result anyway while the former is faster )

```
dft_matrix = np.fft.fft(np.eye(nelems))
```

2. Second, I compute, say, the 20th row of the DFT from first principles using the cosine function

```
fi = 20
dotprod_row_test = np.cos(2 * np.pi * fi * np.linspace(0, 1, nelems))
```

If I compare the resulting values in the 20th row of these two, they don't match exactly?
[image]

BACKGROUND:
I was trying to compute the FFT through different methods and I found that the higher frequencies didn't match exactly. Backtracking, I found that the DFT matrix I "compute from first principles" is not correct.

Comment: What does it mean to take a one dimensional FFT of an identifty matrix?

Comment: the result `dft_matrix` is equivalent to the `sp.linalg.dft(nelems)`, it follows from the unitary property of the fourier transform.

Comment: Does it take the matrix as one long vector?

Comment: yeah it does. Btw the answer below solves the issue. Turned out to be a discretization error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below is a slightly modified version of your code which may be useful.  In particular, the main change is with the line:

```
np.cos(2*np.pi/nelems * fi * np.linspace(0, nelems-1, nelems))
```

The original version was not correctly stepping from 0 to nelems-1 in the argument of the cosine.  In particular, the factor should be $\frac{2 \pi}{nelems}$ with the index running from 0 to nelems-1, **not 0 to nelems**.  Please see the code below for a running implementation.

I hope this helps.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

nelems=128

dft_matrix = np.fft.fft(np.eye(nelems))

# First principles direct calculation
fi = 120
dotprod_row_test = np.cos(2*np.pi/nelems * fi * np.linspace(0, nelems-1, nelems))

# Plot one against the other

plt.plot(dotprod_row_test,'+')
plt.plot(np.real(dft_matrix[fi]),'x')
plt.legend(['direct DFT','numpy DFT'])
plt.show()
```